# How can i fix flutter app stuck in loading screen?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a project(as a student) about writing a dictionary application. And now my code can run without an error but my app is stuck in a loading screen loop. Please help me.

ps. My English isn’t so great but I’ll try, please forgive me if I make a few mistakes

There is a problem with this area.

```
  _search() async {
    if (_controller.text == null || _controller.text.length == 0) {
      _streamController.add(null);
      return;
    }

    _streamController.add("waiting");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(_url + _controller.text.trim());
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri,
        headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + _token});
    _streamController.add(json.decode(response.body));
  }
```

And here is all of my code.

````
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "FlutterDemo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _url = "https://owlbot.info";
  String _token = "My token";

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  late StreamController _streamController;
  late Stream _stream;

  _search() async {
    if (_controller.text == null || _controller.text.length == 0) {
      _streamController.add(null);
      return;
    }

    _streamController.add("waiting");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(_url + _controller.text.trim());
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri,
        headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + _token});
    _streamController.add(json.decode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _streamController = StreamController();
    _stream = _streamController.stream;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flictionary"),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(48.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (String text) {},
                    controller: _controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search for a word",
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _search();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _stream,
          builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return Center(
                child: Text("Enter a search word"),
              );
            }

            if(snapshot.data == "waiting"){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data["definitions"].length,
               itemBuilder: (context, int index){
              return ListBody(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: snapshot.data["definitions"][index]["image_url"] == null 
                      ? null: 
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data["definitions"][index]["image_url"]),
                      ),
                      title: Text(_controller.text.trim() + "(" + snapshot.data["definitions"][index]["type"] + ")"),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot.data["definitions"][index]["definitions"]),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: why not use Streambuilder and bloc code to handle your splash screen?  within the bloc could start a timer.  if the user presses on the form then stop the timer with an event and pop the form.  within your bloc could call your authorization and push a state after complete

Comment: what is the behavior of the text input on the ui?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "FlutterDemo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String _url = "https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/";
  final String _token = "Your Api key here";

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  late StreamController _streamController;
  late Stream _stream;

  _search() async {
    if (_controller.text.isEmpty) {
      _streamController.add(null);
      return;
    }

    _streamController.add("waiting");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(_url + _controller.text.trim());
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri,
        headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + _token});
    var jsoon = json.decode(response.body);
    print(jsoon["definitions"]);
    _streamController.add(json.decode(response.body)["definitions"]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _streamController = StreamController();
    _stream = _streamController.stream;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dictionary"),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(48.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (String text) {},
                    controller: _controller,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search for a word",
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: _search,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _stream,
          builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return const Center(
                child: Text("Enter a search word"),
              );
            }

            if(snapshot.data == "waiting"){
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, int index){
               print(snapshot.data.length);
              return ListBody(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: snapshot.data[index]["image_url"] == null 
                      ? null: 
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]["image_url"]),
                      ),
                      title: Text(_controller.text.trim() + "(" + snapshot.data[index]["definition"] + ")"),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index]["definition"]),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You were modeling your data wrong and API used was not upto standards presented at the documentation

https://owlbot.info/api-reference#tag/English-Dictionary

Refer the link above...

This is working...

async should be imported for stream controller...

body is not required for onPressed you can directly point to the function.

unless you want to add more funtionality.

Comment: I have resolved your code... See the difference of what I have changed you will get the idea where you did mistakes...

Comment: dont share API keys like that... You could be billed